# qwidget.setGeometry() incorrect position on linux

Tags: python, qt, pyside, maya

I'm trying to overlay maya's active view 3d with a qt widget.

I've a canvas base class (a transparent widget), on which I can do some paint stuff. It's parent is the wrapped avtice 3d view.
As soon as the active 3d view is resized The CanvasEventFilter.resize_event signal is emitted in order to resize the canvas widget.

On mac and windows everything works perfectly.
On linux however the widget is offset. The values I get from mapToGlobal() seem to be correct.
However setGeometry() does not update the widgets position and size as I'd expect it to.

What am I missing here?

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QPainterPath
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Signal, Slot, QEvent, QPointF, QPoint
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import shiboken2



class CanvasEventFilter(QObject):
    resize_event = Signal(QEvent)

    def __init__(self):
        super(CanvasEventFilter, self).__init__()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize:
            self.resize_event.emit(event)

        return False

class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Canvas, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        #  self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        #  self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        #  self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_PaintOnScreen)
        #  self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

        self.canvas_event_filter = CanvasEventFilter()
        self.install_event_filter()
        self.resize()
        self.show()

    def install_event_filter(self):
        self.canvas_event_filter.resize_event.connect(self.resize)
        view_wdg = window_utils.active_view_wdg()
        view_wdg.installEventFilter(self.canvas_event_filter)

    def remove_event_filter(self):
        view_wdg = active_view_wdg()
        view_wdg.removeEventFilter(self.canvas_event_filter)

    @Slot(QEvent)
    def resize(self):
        view_wdg = active_view_wdg()
        wdg_size = view_wdg.rect()
        wdg_pos = view_wdg.pos()
        abs_pos = view_wdg.mapToGlobal(wdg_pos)
        self.setGeometry(abs_pos.x(), abs_pos.y(), wdg_size.width(), wdg_size.height())

    def __del__(self):
        self.remove_event_filter()


def active_view_wdg():
    view = omui.M3dView.active3dView()
    active_view_widget = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(view.widget()), QWidget)
    return active_view_widget
```

black widget on mac exactly where it is expected to be. On linux it is offset

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work perfectly for me on Centos 7.
The widget follows when the main window is moving, and resizes properly when the main window is being resized.

I had to rename your `resize` method, as that was accidentally overriding the widget's `QtWidgets.QWidget.resize` method (or just needed to use `super` instead). Instead of `setGeometry` I can simply use `QtWidgets.QWidget.resize`. Also I had to remove `Qt.SplashScreen`, otherwise it wasn't following or resizing properly:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QPainterPath
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Signal, Slot, QEvent, QPointF, QPoint, QSize
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import shiboken2


class CanvasEventFilter(QObject):
    resize_event = Signal(QEvent)

    def __init__(self):
        super(CanvasEventFilter, self).__init__()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize:
            self.resize_event.emit(event)

        return False


class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Canvas, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint  | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:black;}")
        self.canvas_event_filter = CanvasEventFilter()
        self.install_event_filter()
        self.resize_event()
        self.show()

    def install_event_filter(self):
        self.canvas_event_filter.resize_event.connect(self.resize_event)
        view_wdg = active_view_wdg()
        view_wdg.installEventFilter(self.canvas_event_filter)

    def remove_event_filter(self):
        view_wdg = active_view_wdg()
        view_wdg.removeEventFilter(self.canvas_event_filter)

    @Slot(QEvent)
    def resize_event(self):
        view_wdg = active_view_wdg()
        wdg_size = view_wdg.rect()
        wdg_pos = view_wdg.pos()
        abs_pos = view_wdg.mapToGlobal(wdg_pos)
        self.resize(wdg_size.width(), wdg_size.height())

    def __del__(self):
        self.remove_event_filter()


def active_view_wdg():
    view = omui.M3dView.active3dView()
    active_view_widget = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(view.widget()), QWidget)
    return active_view_widget

tool = Canvas(active_view_wdg())
tool.show()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank! That solves the positioning and resize problem! 
However, it's still not working as it is on mac or win.
The widget is resizing but I get those odd artifacts as if the widget is not dating up correctly.
Maybe an ideas on that one as well? I'm on centos7 as well.
![img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab6SA.png).

Comment: I can confirm I'm getting the same refresh issue on my Windows machine.